# What update I have to install in Foundation 2010 to run a backup that asks for version 4.1.13.0?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, backup

I'm trying to run a backup from a Sharepoint Server 2010 that runs a version 14.0.6101.5008:

[image]

The version of my local Sharepoint Foundation 2010 server is 14.0.6114.5000:

[image]

When I run the backup from the first server in my local Sharepoint Foundation 2010 server, this error happens:

[image]

The message is in Portuguese and say: "The backup file should be restored to a server with version "4.1.13.0" or later."

How can I run this backup in my local Sharepoint Foundation 2010 server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message in English is:

> Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoint
>   Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the current
>   version. The backup file should be restored to a server with version
>   '4.1.13.0' or later.

This is not referring to your server build number but to the **database schema version of your content database**. This should have been done when you applied the previous updates but is often skipped if the configuration wizard isn't properly run. To do it in Powershell just use this command:

```
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase -Identity SOMEDATABASE_CONTENT
```

Just replace `SOMEDATABASE_CONTENT` with the name of your content database you are restoring too.

---

Documentation here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607813.aspx